# In Selenium (Python) - how to click a button _only after_ a file is uploaded?

Tags: python, exception, selenium, selenium-webdriver, timeout

Using Selenium, I have a problem clicking on the submit button *only after* a file is uploaded.

In the demonstration code below - only after the file finishes uploading in the `g` element, the `submit` element should be clicked.

However, I seem unable to correctly use `wait.until` to achieve the above.
Namely, even though the file seems to be fully uploaded (the timeout is 30 seconds and the file is only 56kB) - I get the following **timeout exception:**

```
sh-4.1$ ./stackoverflow_selenium_example.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./stackoverflow_selenium_example.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "./stackoverflow_selenium_example.py", line 42, in main
    elem = wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.ID,'g'),fax["document"]))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: '' 
sh-4.1$
```

**Notes:**

1. The **`submit`** element is: `<input type="submit" id="sub" name="submit" value="שלחו פקס">`
2. The **`g`** element is: `<input class="fileUpload0" id="g" data-file='' data-func='upload' type="file" name="files[]" style="">`

**Python Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import selenium.common.exceptions
import os
import time

AWHILE = 30
SHORT_TIME = 10

def main():
        url = "http://www.freefax.co.il"
        email = "a.b@c.com"

        fax = {}
        fax["document"] = r"C:\tmp\DevOpsTest.pdf"
        fax["description"] = "Example of selenium problem"
        fax["numbers"] = r"04-000-0001"

        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, AWHILE)

        driver.get(url + os.sep + "upload.php")
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name("Desc")
        elem.send_keys(fax["description"])
        elem = driver.find_element_by_id("NumberList0")
        elem.send_keys(fax["numbers"])
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
        elem.send_keys(email)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name("Yes")
        elem.click()

        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 0);")
        elem = driver.find_element_by_id("g")
        elem.send_keys(fax["document"])
        elem = wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.ID,'g'),fax["document"]))
        elem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,'submit')))
        elem.click()

        # Show next screen for a short time.
        time.sleep(SHORT_TIME)
        driver.quit() # end the whole session.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Screen-capture at time of exception**

[image: Screen-capture]

**Environment:**

```
    Selenium: selenium (2.37.2)
    Chrome: Version 33.0.1750.154 m
    Cygein: CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 1.7.28(0.271/5/3) i686 
    Windows: 7 Ultimate
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just learning Selenium.

While entering text you are locating the element by ID but for checkpoint you are using NAME. Should you not use ID in the checkpoint as well?

Comment: I think it's a case of "A rose by any other name" - but probably to be more Pythonic I should be consistent in how I reference. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that the element has the same ID and NAME attributes? The error clearly says that selenium is timing out while trying to find the element. I don't see any other problem here.

Comment: Mae culpa: indeed I was using By.NAME instead of By.ID.  
However, even after fixing this typo, I'm still getting:  

Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "./stackoverflow_selenium_example.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "./stackoverflow_selenium_example.py", line 42, in main
    elem = wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.ID,'g'),fax["document"]))  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: ''